# wordpress recursive zip folder file download php / path issue

Tags: php, wordpress, zip, directory, recursive-query

I know there is quite some code out there about that topic. But I can't get the code I found to work...

I'm using a function that comes from a Wordpress plugin called Zip-Attachments.
So I modified it to zip files from a specific folder. BUT it doesn't work....

It seems as if I'm missing something when it comes to accurately assigning a paths within the RecursiveDirectoryIterator class.

I was able to zip a single file and downloading it without the recursiveIteration functionality and passing the absolute path as a string. So the main part of the function works.

What am I missing to make that function work?

Here is my non working code:

```
function za_create_zip_callback(){

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$rootPath = $upload_dir['basedir'];
$upload_dir_Knippsbox = 'Knippsbox';

// Prepare File
$file = tempnam($upload_dir['path'], "zip");
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// create recursive directory iterator
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("{$rootPath}/{$upload_dir_Knippsbox}/"), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

// let's iterate
foreach ($files as $name => $fileX) {
   $filePath = $fileX->getRealPath();
   $zip->addFile($filePath);
}

//Close the file
$zip->close();

// Add a download to the Counter

    global $wpdb;
    $meta_name = "_za_counter";

    // Retrieve the meta value from the DB

    $za_download_count = get_post_meta($postId, $meta_name, true) != '' ? get_post_meta($postId, $meta_name, true) : '0';
    $za_download_count = $za_download_count + 1;

    // Update the meta value

    update_post_meta($postId, $meta_name, $za_download_count);

// We have to return an actual URL, that URL will set the headers to force the download
echo zip_attachments_url."/download.php?za_pretty_filename=".sanitize_file_name($pretty_filename)."&za_real_filename=".$filename;

die();}
```

Desperately looking for your expert views...
Thanks,
Ben

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? Do you get errors? Does it run at all? If so, does it not zip? What's the issue?

Comment: I get this as an Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in /mnt/webv/b3/75/56978175/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-content/plugins/zip-attachments/zip-attachments.php

However, it seems like it is a path problem in detail.

How do I have to use variables to point to a specific directory within my wp-content/upload folder?

Comment: Which line is that in the code above?  (Meaning which line in the code above is throwing the error)?